# Error:Could not download gson.jar (com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2): No cached version available for offline mode

Tags: java, android, caching, gson

Gradle sync failed: Could not download gson.jar (com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2): No cached version available for offline mode
         Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Comment: use com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0

Comment: how can i do please

Comment: can you post your build.gradle where you declare the GSON dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Gradle is in offline mode. You will have to uncheck "Offline Work" in your settings to disable the offline mode.

Go to settings, search for "offline", select & uncheck the offline work. Then turn on your internet connection and sync again.